# In ASP.NET Core Web API - Swagger did not show correct list into list

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this method for add

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromForm] AddMovieViewModel model)
{
    return ok();
}
```

with this model:

```
public class AddMovieViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ReleasedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? IMDB { get; set; }
    public int? Time { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? Image { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? Cover { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
    
    public List<FileViewModel> Files { get; set; }
 }
```

With field `Files` being of type:

```
public class FileViewModel
{
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Quality { get; set; }
    public byte? Season { get; set; }
    public byte? Episode { get; set; }

    public IFormFile? File { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to add, it shows a string input:

```
{
  "quality": "string",
  "season": 0,
  "episode": 0,
  "file": "string"
}
```

[Image Of Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrZTX.png)

I use Swagger document but that didn't help me

Comment: What exactly do you expect instead of `string`?

Comment: Chose file option

Comment: It seems like Swagger is not recognizing the IFormFile type and is displaying the FileViewModel property as a string in the Swagger UI. Have you tried with SwaggerRequestExample attribute?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron 
yes swagger did not recognize Iformfile In List ,
but in postman i can call Api Easily